# Single app registration in Microsoft Account Developer Center / Application Registration Portal

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-mobile-services, windows-dev-center

I'd like to connect multiple UWP apps and have a single Mobile App in Azure that uses Authentication / Authorization using a Microsoft Account. It looks like you can only associate the Mobile App to a single app registered in the Microsoft Account Developer Center / Application Registration Portal.

Is there any way around this to "funnel" multiple UWP apps to authenticate through a single registered app in the Microsoft Account Developer Center and single Mobile App in Azure?

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom authentication scenario.  Basically, you submit the token you receive from the MSA identity provider to a custom API.  The custom API will validate that the token is valid and comes from a recognized app, then it mints a new token for accessing the mobile app and returns it to the client.